# MySQL performance - large database

Tags: mysql

I've read heaps of posts here on stackoverflow, blog posts, tutorials and more, but I still fail to resolve a rather nasty performance issue with my MySQL db. Keep in mind that I'm a novice when it comes to large MySQL databases.

I have a table with approx. 11.000.000 rows (will increase to say 20.000.000 or more). Here's the layout:

```
CREATE TABLE `myTable` (
  `intcol1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `charcol1` char(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `intcol2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `charcol2` char(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `charcol3` char(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `charcol4` char(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `intcol3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `charcol5` char(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `intcol4` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `intcol5` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `intcol6` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `intcol7` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `idx` (`charcol2`,`charcol3`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=11665231 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

A select statement like

`SELECT * from myTable where charchol2='bogus' AND charcol3='bogus2';`

takes 25 seconds or so to execute. That's too slow, and will be even slower as the table grows.

The table will not have any inserts or updates at all (so to speak), and will be primarily used for outputting searches on the char-columns.

I've tried to make indexing work (playing around with FULLTEXT, as you can see), but it seems that I'm missing something. Any takes on how to speed up the performance?

Please note: Im currently running MySQL on my Macbook Air (1.7 GHz i5, 4GB RAM). If this is the only answer to my performance issues, I'll move the database to something appropriate ;-)

EDIT: Explain table

id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  myTable ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    11596725    Using where

Comment: Please, provide EXPLAIN results for your query. I don't think, you need a fulltext index for these queries

Comment: Query takes 25 seconds to execute, but how many rows did you receive? What's your index cardinality for mentioned indexes? Why MyISAM and not InnoDB (configured to use 80% of your RAM)?

Comment: I think like @user4035, that you don't need a fulltext index. But if you want to know what mysql is doing try Explain(SELECT * from myTable where charchol2='bogus' AND charcol3='bogus2') to check if mysql can use the index etc.

Comment: @N.B.: 6 rows received. MyISAM because I wanted to try fulltext. Speed is more or less the same with InnoDB though.

Comment: @user4035: Explain show this:


id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra 
1 SIMPLE myTable ALL idx NULL NULL NULL 11596668 Using where

Comment: @DataEditor For some reason, it doesn't use your index, try to DROP INDEX idx; Then create a normal index ALTER TABLE `myTable` ADD INDEX `charchol_idx` (`charchol2`, `charchol3`); Let me know, whether it helped.

Comment: InnoDB in MySQL 5.6 supports fulltext indexes. MyISAM and InnoDB aren't the same beast, therefore they can't perform the same. You said you browsed for help on SO, but you didn't provide the usual information - table structure, EXPLAIN / EXPLAIN EXTENDED output, how many rows you receive using the example query etc.

Comment: @user4035 Thanks, I'll try that. How can I see that the index isn't used?

Comment: @DataEditor In the output, given by EXPLAIN you see `key` column. It says: NULL (better edit your post), and put explain table there

Comment: Have you tried normal composite index on these columns (not full text key)?

Comment: @user4035 I changed engine to InnoDB and followed your advice. Works like a charm now. Thanks a million! Made my day!

Comment: @DataEditor I put it as an answer, please, accept it, so everybody could see, that your question is solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create FULLTEXT indexes for such requests, where equality operator is used. Just create an index on every char field, that will be used in WHERE condition, and remove the fulltext index:

```
DROP INDEX idx;
ALTER TABLE myTable ADD INDEX charchol_idx (charchol2, charchol3);
```